# Need help realigning python fill_between with data points

Tags: python, pandas, outliers, rolling-computation, anomaly-detection

Alert! I am feeling so embarassed asking such an entry level question here!!!!

Hey guys, I have been working on a project that involves timeseries total electron content data. My goal is to apply statistical analysis and find anomalies in TEC due to earthquake.

I am following [this research paper for sliding IQR method](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/375029615_A_comprehensive_study_on_the_synchronized_outgoing_longwave_radiation_and_relative_humidity_anomalies_related_to_global_Mw_65_earthquakes). But for some reason I am not getting results as shown in the paper with the given formulas. So I decided to use the rolling mean + 1.6 STD method.

The problem is when I use ax.fill_between(x1 = index, y1 = ub, y2=lb) method my confidence interval band is being plotted a step further than the data point. Please see the given figure for a better understanding.

Here's what I am currently doing:

```
df = DAEJ.copy()
window = 12
hourly = df.resample(rule="h").median()
hourly["ma"] = hourly["TEC"].rolling(window=window).mean()
hourly["hour"] = hourly.index.hour
hourly["std_err"] = hourly["TEC"].rolling(window=window).std()
hourly["ub"] = hourly["ma"] + (1.67* hourly["std_err"])
hourly["lb"] = hourly["ma"] - (1.67* hourly["std_err"])
hourly["sig2"] = hourly["TEC"].rolling(window=window).var()
hourly["kur"] = hourly["TEC"].rolling(window=window).kurt()
hourly["pctChange"] = hourly.TEC.pct_change(12, fill_method="bfill")
hourly = hourly.dropna()
dTEC = hourly[(hourly["TEC"] > hourly["ub"])]



fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,4))
hourly["TEC"].plot(ax=ax, title="TEC Anomaly", label="Station: DAEJ")
ax.fill_between(x=hourly.index, y1=hourly["ub"], y2=hourly["lb"], color="red", label="Conf Interval", alpha=.4)
ax.legend()
```

And here's the result I got!

[image: TEC Anomaly detection using rolling std method]

as seen in the given figure the data and the colored band aren't alinged properly, I know after calculating a rolling mean with a window of 12 hours will result in a 12 hour shifted value but even after dropping the first values I am still not getting an aligned figure.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] of `df`

Comment: Your file is not accessible.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nUv9h4qfux_YLBzERsgJ4d3b5WDlVpOP/view?usp=sharing

Comment: changed the access rights

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to center your [`rolling`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) windows with `center=True`:

```
window = 12
hourly = df.resample(rule="h").median()
hourly["ma"] = hourly["TEC"].rolling(window=window, center=True).mean()
hourly["hour"] = hourly.index.hour
hourly["std_err"] = hourly["TEC"].rolling(window=window, center=True).std()
hourly["ub"] = hourly["ma"] + (1.67* hourly["std_err"])
hourly["lb"] = hourly["ma"] - (1.67* hourly["std_err"])
hourly["sig2"] = hourly["TEC"].rolling(window=window, center=True).var()
hourly["kur"] = hourly["TEC"].rolling(window=window, center=True).kurt()
hourly["pctChange"] = hourly.TEC.pct_change(12, fill_method="bfill")
hourly = hourly.dropna()
dTEC = hourly[(hourly["TEC"] > hourly["ub"])]
```

Alternatively, what you tried to do should have been done with [`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html):

```
# your original code
# ...

# then shift
ax.fill_between(x=hourly.index, y1=hourly["ub"].shift(-window//2),
                y2=hourly["lb"].shift(-window//2),
                color="red", label="Conf Interval", alpha=.4)
```

Output:

[image]